# trying to change image of a component in vue js but it's touching the entire row

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

so i'm trying to change the img src on hover events on a component.
it works but since i use v-for, it change every image in the row instead of one.
here is the code in main.js :

```
Vue.component("fiche-produit", {
            template: `<div class="col-3">
                            <img v-bind:src="image" width="380px">             
                        </div>`,
            props: ["image"],
            methods: {},
        });
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: function () {
                return {
                    hover: false,
                    produits: [{
                            id: "1",
                            nom: "",
                            image: "img/coupe-vent-home-menthe.jpg",
                            image2: "img/technique_mente2.jpg",
                            prix: "",
                        },
                        {
                            id: "2",
                            nom: "",
                            image: "img/Bas_de_jogging_technique_menthe1.jpg",
                            image2: "img/Bas_de_jogging_technique_menthe2.jpg",

                            prix: "",
                        },
                        {
                            id: "3",
                            nom: "",
                            image: "img/coupe-vent-home-noir.jpg",
                            image2: "img/coupe-vent-home-noir2.jpg",
                            prix: "",
                        },
                        {
                            id: "4",
                            nom: "",
                            image: "img/bas_technique_noir.jpg",
                            image2: "img/bas_technique_noir2.jpg",
                            prix: "",
                        }
                    ],
                };
            },
        });
```

here is the html code:

```
<div id="app">
        <fiche-produit v-for="produit in produits" @mouseover.native="hover = true" @mouseleave.native="hover = false"
            v-bind:image="[hover ? produit.image2 : produit.image]"></fiche-produit>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple `produits` but only a single `hover` state variable, which is shared by all of them. If you want each to have their own hover state, you will need separate variables. You can either have a `hover` array of the same length as `produits`, or just add a `hover` attribute to each.

For example:

```
<fiche-produit v-for="produit in produits"
               @mouseover.native="$set(produit, 'hover', true)" 
               @mouseleave.native="$set(produit, 'hover', false)"
               v-bind:image="[produit.hover ? produit.image2 : produit.image]"
               :key="produit.id">
</fiche-produit>
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so much it works !!  i was so desperate :(

Comment: by the way do you know to add animation on hover event ?